# Android replace a fragment with an activity into a framelayout

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a navigation drawer project with some fragments, now I want to call an activity from the menu.
The fragments are loaded into a framelayout and replaced with a new fragment on click event menu with a transaction.
When I click on the menu item I call this code:

```
fragment = new HomeFragment();
fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit();
```

Now if I call an activity with this code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, asd.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

the activity override the entire navigation drawer because I don't replace the existing fragment into frame_container with the new activity.

How can I do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fragment can be added to the container. Activity hosts a fragment. What is happening is you are Navigating to a different Activity. You have a drawer in MainActivity not asd.

If you want a drawer in asd also create a BaseActivtiy that has NavigationDrawer and extend from it.

Answer (score 1):

Your Navigation Drawer and the FrameLayout, all are inside one Activity where in you can replace the fragments and at the same time drawer will be visible.

However, when you start a new Activity, a new screen appears which do not have the implementation of the Navigation Drawer as it belongs to your first Activity only.

Use @Raghunandan's way and create a new BaseActivity which is extended by both of your Activites (one containing FrameLayout and the other one) or in case it is possible to use another Fragment instead of an Activity then create a new fragment then you can simply replace the new one in your FrameLayout and you will have the NavigationDrawer as well. :)